# JOIN function parameters

Tags: excel, vba

How can I pass a range to my function for example I have uperlimit and lowerlimit.
uperlimit=x_row
lowerlimit=y_row

```
CONCATENARCELDAS(B21:B31)
```

I want something like this but is not working

```
CONCATENARCELDAS("B"&uperlimit:"B"&lowerlimit)
```

code that concatenate values

```
Function CONCATENARCELDAS(Rango As Range)
For Each Celda In Rango.Cells

If Celda.Value <> "" Then
    resultado = resultado & " | " & Celda.Offset(0, -1)

End If

Next Celda

resultado = Right(resultado, Len(resultado) - 2)

CONCATENARCELDAS = resultado

End Function
```

Comment: If you are using vba, remember always to use english name of the functions.

Comment: spanish excel i know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=CONCATENARCELDAS(INDEX(B:B,E1):INDEX(B:B,E2))
```

[image]

Comment: Im getting #!VALOR! on the output cell, Im using the custom function above but the range is variable lets say between row 21 and 33 for 1 example and I want to pass those rows to the custom concatenate function above

Comment: INDEX in Spanish is `INDICE` and check to ensure you use `,` and not `;` in the formula.

Comment: Where do you get those numbers? and do not be flippant, we are trying to help, remember we are volunteers not paid employees.  In this instance you would replace the Upperlimit and LowerLimit with a cell address in which you put the numbers.

Comment: thats exactly what I wanted, could not make it work in VBA but in excel works perfect, thank you for the clear example